# How to use exported data as input in SAP with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am writing a VBA script to check all measuring point, who are part of the selection have inspection orders. For this I need to extract a large amount of measering point (ca. 2721) and use them as an input in another transaction.

The problem I have is: What is the most efficient way to extract / export a large amount of data from SAP in a way that I can paste them as an input in SAP?

I can make an export, but I cannot access the exported Excel-file through VBA. I can loop through the datarows and copy every single cell, but this is very slow, as shown below.

```
row = 1
For i = 1 To session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").RowCount - 2
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").CurrentCellRow = i    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output2").Cells(row, 1) = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(i - 1, "TPLNR")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output2").Cells(row, 2) = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(i - 1, "POINT")
    row = row + 1
Next
```

Comment: In which formats can you export the data from SAP?

Comment: I use an Excel File

Answer (score 1):

You should

- use an array - instead of writing directly to the sheet
- use `with` to not call `session.FindByID...` multiple times

```vb
Dim arrData As Variant, i As Long

With session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
    
    ReDim arrData(1 To .RowCount - 2, 1 To 2)
    
    For i = 1 To .RowCount - 2
        .CurrentCellRow = i
        arrData(i, 1) = .GetCellValue(i - 1, "TPLNR")
        arrData(i, 2) = .GetCellValue(i - 1, "POINT")
    Next
    
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output2")
    .Resize(UBound(arrData, 1), 2).Value = arrData
End With
```

But maybe it's worth to look into Powerquery to achieve what you want.